# downloading file using scp command

Tags: unix, terminal

I have a centos server lets say with ip: 1.2.3.4. I want to download a file from 1.2.3.4 at path /root/pc/filename.rar to my localhost host (current pc). What command I need to download that file? I am trying like this but its not working

```
scp root@1.2.3.4:/root/pcfilename.rar
```

I want to download that file into my system current directory.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Just add where you want it to be copied to (ie: `./`):

```
scp root@1.2.3.4:/root/pcfilename.rar ./
```

Comment: how can I download file with required rsa file and port

Comment: It should `ssh -i /path/to/id_rsa -P 2222 root@1.2.3.4/root/pcfilename.rar ./` the character P should be uppercase .

Answer (score 15):

First of all, make sure that the root user is really needed to access the file. If the file can be retrieved by a normal user, that would be preferred to limit the security risks.

If root is really required, make sure that root is actually allowed to login by ssh by checking your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and see if the `PermitRootLogin` option is set to `yes`.

Finally, your command above should work when you add a `.` (pointing to your current dir) behind it, like so:

```
scp root@1.2.3.4:/root/pcfilename.rar .
```

Or you can always use a full path as well:

```
scp root@1.2.3.4:/root/pcfilename.rar /home/user/pcfilename.rar
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm using

> > rsync -avz example@x.x.x.x:/home/example/* .

This example will deliver files inside the folder (-a switch), will print the process (-v switch, verbose) and will use compression during the transfer (-z switch). The dot in the beginning tells rsync to deliver the files in the current folder. Otherwise you could replace the dot (.) with a folder, say /home/foo/bar

Comment: The question specifically asks how to do this with `scp`. Since the other answers show that it is possible to do it in `scp`, there’s no need to present a solution using a different utility. You don’t offer any reason why an `rsync` solution is preferable, and what you do say is unclear.